# Number of maximal squares in a m X n matrix

Tags: algorithm

The problem is :

> Given a matrix of order M x N containing 1.s and 0's, you have to find
>   the number of maximal squares that can be formed. A square is formed
>   by grouping adjacent cells containing 1. A maximal square is one that
>   is not completely contained within another square. Maximal squares
>   that overlap partially are to be counted separately. Unit squares
>   (length of side = 1) should be also counted.  Note that squares are
>   filled, i.e. they cannot contain 0.s.  What can be the best possible
>   algorithm ?

Example :

For the following 4x5 matrix the input will be :

Sample Input and Output:

```
11001
11110
11011
11001
```

Output:

```
9
```

Comment: What have you tried? And also counting the squares of size 1 this is way more then 9(you have more then 9 ones)

Comment: There are 6 unit squares and three 2x2 squares.

Comment: @izomorphius we need to find out the number of maximal squares , not *plain* squares and the maximal square can not include a full square . It can have intersection , though

Comment: @ShamimHafiz see acraig5075 comment on how the count is 9.

Comment: This is IBM ISL programming assignment. Today is deadline for submission. Based on the assignment interviews will be scheduled.

Comment: @user875036 What is ISL ? What does IBM has to do with it ? I do not get you .

Answer (score 3):

Let `S(i,j)` be the size of the largest square with bottom-right corner at `(i,j)`. (My indices run from top to bottom and left to right, and they start from 1.) The whole `S` is an `M x N` matrix of integers. Computing `S` is a very classical problem in dynamic programming, which is known to have O(MN) time complexity. (In case you don't remember, here's how it's done. Suppose `A` is the input matrix. You set `S(i,j) = 0` if `A(i,j) = 0`, and set `S(i,j) = min(S(i-1,j), S(i,j-1), S(i-1,j-1))+1` if `A(i,j) = 1`. You can set `S(0,j) = S(i,0) = 0` if you like.)

Then you extract maximal squares by examining the matrix `S`. The square with bottom-right corner at `(i,j)` is maximal if and only if `S(i,j)` is non-zero and is greater than or equal to `S(i+1,j)`, `S(i,j+1)` and `S(i+1,j+1)`. (Set `S(M+1,j) = 0` and `S(i,N+1) = 0` if you like.) This step also takes O(MN) time.

Comment: I'm new here so I can't comment on other's posts. user875036 tried to implement my algorithm but he made a mistake in the `else` case in the last loop. `if (S[row][column > 0) nSquares++;` is wrong.

Comment: And I just realized he forgot the condition "`S(i,j)` is non-zero". I will correct his post now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my overlook. I corrected the program. Your algorithm rocks. It worked correctly.

Comment: Too bad I gain no reputation for giving it, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Possible 4x4 squares have top-lefts at (0,0) and (1,0).

Possible 3x3 squares have top-lefts at (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1).

Possible 2x2 squares have top-lefts at (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2).

Possible 1x1 squares have top lefts at all coordinates.

So an algorithm could go as follows:

Start with testing for 4x4's, and if all 1's, mark as belonging to a 4x4, and increment count.

Then test for 3x3's, and if all 1's and not marked as belonging to a 4x4, then mark as belonging to a 3x3, and increment count.

Then test for 2x2's, and if all 1's and not marked as belonging to a 4x4 or 3x3, then mark as belonging to a 2x2, and increment count.

Then test for 1x1's, and if 1 and not marked at all, then increment count.

Return the count.

How you mark a cell will be language specific. e.g. with C I'd use a bit-field.

**EDIT:** For fun I implemented this in Java using Bitset.

```
import java.util.BitSet; 

public class Program
    {
    // Right-shift bits by 'n' places
    private static BitSet RightShift(BitSet x, int n)
        {
        return x.get(n, Math.max(n, x.length()));
        }

    // Test square of dimension 'size' with top-left at position (h,w) for maximal-ness
    public static boolean IsMaximalSquare(BitSet [][] matrix, int h, int w, int size)
    {
        boolean isMaximal = true;
        for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < size; b++)
            {
                BitSet x = matrix[h + a][w + b];
                if (!x.get(0))
                    return false;
                x = RightShift(x, size + 1);
                if (!x.isEmpty())
                    isMaximal = false;
            }
        }

        if (!isMaximal)
            return false;

        for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < size; b++)
                matrix[h + a][w + b].set(size);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Populate a 2d array of bitsets from string array
    public static BitSet [][] BuildMatrix(String rows[])
    {
        BitSet [][] matrix = new BitSet[4][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = new BitSet(5);
                matrix[i][j].set(0, '1' == rows[i].charAt(j));
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    // Return number of maximal squares from string representation of array
    public static int Solve(String rows[])
    {
        BitSet [][] matrix = BuildMatrix(rows);

        int count = 0;

        for (int size = 4; size > 0; size--) // test squares of size 4x4, 3x3, 2x2 and 1x1
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < 5 - size; h++) // iterate the rows
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < 6 - size; w++) // iterate the columns
                {
                    if (IsMaximalSquare(matrix, h, w, size))
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        String rows1[] = {"11001","11110","11011","11001"}; // original question
        String rows2[] = {"11111","11111","11111","11111"}; // additional test case 1
        String rows3[] = {"00000","00000","00000","00000"}; // additional test case 2
        String rows4[] = {"11100","11111","11111","00111"}; // additional test case 3
        String rows5[] = {"11101","11111","11111","10111"}; // additional test case 4

        System.out.println(Solve(rows1));
        System.out.println(Solve(rows2));
        System.out.println(Solve(rows3));
        System.out.println(Solve(rows4));
        System.out.println(Solve(rows5));
        }
    }
```

Comment: what can be the best possible way of cell marking in Java ?

Comment: @Geek I don't know about the best way, but you could use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) or [byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563544/java-bit-manipulation). So along with your array of integers being the matrix, you could have another same-sized array of `BitSet`'s storing the markings. Or neater would be to have just one array of [tuples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) being the value and it's marker.

Comment: @Geek: I've updated my post with code (despite the homework tag!)