# Can I shift bits into an integer that is initially 0 using a for loop that iterates 8 times to get some 8-bit number in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, binary, bit-shift

I am working on implementing an ***8-bit adder*** abstracted with code in Java. This 8-bit adder is built from 8 ***full adder*** circuits. For those who don't know what a full adder is, it's a circuit that computes the sum of 2 bits.

My intention was8-bit  to use a for loop to add each corresponding bit of the adders 2, 8-bit inputs such that a new bit of the 8-bit result is computed each time the for loop iterates.

***Would it be possible to store the new computed bit of each iteration in a variable holding the 8-bit result using bit shifting?***

Here's an example to help explain what I am asking. *The bold bit would be the one that is shifted into the int holding the result.*

> 0b00001010

+

> 0b00001011

**First Iteration (addition starting w/ LSB)**

> Sum: 1
>
> Result: 0b0000000**1**
>
> Carry: 0

**Second Iteration**

> Sum: 0
>
> Result: 0b000000**0**1
>
> Carry: 1

**Third Iteration**

> Sum: 1
>
> Result: 0b00000**1**01
>
> Carry: 0

**Fourth Iteration**

> Sum: 0
>
> Result: 0b0000**0**101
>
> Carry: 1

**Fifth Iteration**

> Sum: 1
>
> Result: 0b000**1**0101
>
> Carry: 0

**Sixth, Seventh, Eigth Iteration**

> Sum: 0, 0, 0 respectively
>
> Result: 0b**000**10101
>
> Carry: 0, 0, 0 respectively

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563544/java-bit-manipulation#563564

Answer (score 1):

The shift operators in java are : **>>>**, **<<**  and **>>** , e.g.

```
System.out.println(1 << 1); // print 2
System.out.println(1 << 2); // print 4
```

You can't insert 1 from thin air with shifting. To insert 1 try bitwise operators: **|** and **&**

Comment: Beat me to it. The definite issue here is that you can't change the value of `0b00000000` using bit shifting alone. You've got to get a `1` in there somehow, and shifting can't do that.

Comment: ...at least not in Java. In assembly you just set the carry bit and do a shift-with-carry instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get that exact sequence, you can do it with this operation:

```
n = (n<<1 | (1&~n));
```

Starting from `n=0`, this gives `0b00000001`, `0b00000010`, `0b00000101`, `0b00001010` etc.

Answer (score 0):

refred already mentioned the shift operations.
shift operations are in particular useful when you are creating a bit mask (so lets say 1 bit of the whole number is set, or when a consecutive amount of bits within a bit field should be set.

Remember that
`a = a << 1` is equal to

`a = a*2` or `a*=2` respectively.

And in anology
`a = a >> 2` is equal to

```
a = a/2 or a/= 2
```

Now whenever you don't have consecutive amounts of bits that should be set you have to use binary operations like & and |.
So since you will need binary operations anyway, it does not make that much sense to use shift operations in every case because you could simple write down the hex value. But it would be possible. I made several steps to make this clear:

```
int a = 1;  //0b00000001
a <<= 2     //0b00000100
a |= 1      //0b00000101
a <<= 1     //0b00001010
```